# Semi-positive definite symmetric $(0,2)$ tensors on Riemann manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

We know that a symmetric matrix $S$ could be written as $S=A^TA$ for some $A$ if and only if it is semi-positive definite. Now on a Riemann manifold, given a semi-positive symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor $S$ on it, could we always find some $(1,1)$ tensor $A$ such that $S$ is the composite of $A$ and its transpose? That is, written in local coordinate, $S_{ij}=A^k_iA^l_jg_{kl}$.

Comment: Yes but it won’t necessarily be smooth at any point where $S$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Is there any outline of the proof?

Comment: It's linear algebra. A nonnegative define symmetric matrix has a square root. In fact, it has a square root that is itself a nonnegative definite symmetric matrix.

Comment: I should also correct myself. the square root is not even necessarily continuous.

Comment: Well, that's certainly true, but what I need is a smooth tensor $A$. Is this possible?

Comment: In general no. You can see this in the 1d case, since $\sqrt{a}$ is not a smooth function of $a$. It’s no better in higher dimensions.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the example.

Comment: I need to correct my comment. My counterexample is not a counterexample, because $x$ is not a smooth nonnegative function. Your question in dimension $1$ is locally equivalent to the question of whether a nonnegative smooth function always has a smooth square root. I did not know the answer to this, but apparently the answer is no. See, for example, https://mathoverflow.net/a/105442/613